# Filehelpers library : read mutiple record where each record have fixed length but no line breakup

Tags: filehelpers

I have a flat file where each record are repeating with fixed length but there is no line breakup.

How can I read it using the `filehelpers` library?

Comment: Please edit the question to include a few samples of your records.

Comment: I would second this.  Without a sample of data there are a few speculations that have to be made which could invalidate any answer given.

Answer (score 0):

There are several suggestions, the best of which I think would be to write a pre-parser that reads in the correct record length and then recreates the file with line breaks.  You could do this in memory using a stringbuilder and memorystream's assuming the file is relatively small, otherwise you'll have to write it out to prevent a memory overload.